# Can I apply Django 2.X version to the latest version?

Tags: django

Currently, the latest version of Django is 3.1. I'm not familiar with Django, so I looked for Django lectures, and there were many Django 2.X versions of lectures. Can I apply Django 2.X version lecture to the latest version of Django (3.1 version)?

Comment: Many components would be changed in between different versions. For example, to load static earlier it used to be `{% load static from staticfiles %}`. In Django 3.x it is `{%load static%}`.

Comment: Most of the features in 2.2 are compatible with 3.x. the incompatible things are usually not part of any tutorial you may find. You can go over the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/) to find backwards incompatible changes

Comment: Then isn't there a big influence on me studying the basics of Django?